# Running AutoIT scripts in c#.Net - issue with WinWaitActive

Tags: c#, .net, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am building a windows form application using c#.NET and would like to use AutoITX3.dll to run/perform simple window scripts. I have properly referenced the AutoItX3Lib and following is my code.

I tab through the program to make window "Title" active and yet, the program wouldn't continue with the script and never prints the "ITS ACTIVE" line. It seems to get stuck at WinWaitActive and I am unsure why.

```
autoit = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class();                           
autoit.AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2);   
autoit.WinActivate("Title");
autoit.WinWaitActive("Title");    
System.Console.WriteLine("ITS ACTIVE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the deal with `WinWaitActive("sometitle")`, it will freeze if it can't see the title -- that is, it will wait indefinitely for the window to become active, because it's not seeing it with the parameters that you specified.

---

Solution:
  Use the AutoIt inspector to get the title of the window, and place all that code you have into an **actual** AutoIt script (So you can rule out the possibility of there being an error with the library itself). Then, use that AutoIt script and tune it.

Sometimes, we have trouble matching AutoIt titles with, so what you can do is something like the following:

```
While( True )
     $winTitle = WinGetTitle("[active]")
     $matchText = "Title" ; put the title you want to match here
     $match = WinActive($matchText) ; If this is 0, then it didn't match.
     ConsoleWrite($winTitle & " : " & $match)
WEnd
```

I noticed that you also want to match substrings of the title. I've found it's best to leave that option alone and use regular expressions to match the title.

If you post the title, I'll help you find a regexp or some code to match it and give you the full code to use that in C#.

[Note: I haven't verified any of the code I posted, so I can't guarantee that it will be error-free. I'm on a Mac & I can't test it right now]

Good luck!